# Usage of Google tag manager inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics

I have developed an e-commerce site using Angular 9. There are some third-party web applications that make use of my application. For the purpose of this question, these look like the following:

- App1(My application URL): [www.my-ecommerce.com](http://www.my-ecommerce.com)
- App2(1st third-party) : [www.thirdparty1.com](http://www.thirdparty1.com)
- App3(2nd third-party) : [www.thirdparty2.com](http://www.thirdparty2.com)

App2 and App3 have some buttons. Upon clicking those buttons, **App1** will pop-up in an iframe.

I am trying to add Google Analytics to **App1**.  Google Analytics is not getting any data in this case. When I directly access **App1**, analytics works, but when accessing through other websites, it is not working.

Why not?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default/standard Google Analytics templates, its cookies only work in first-party context. They are subject to [SameSite attribute](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cookies-user-id#cookie_flags). You embedded site won't be able to access the GA cookie(s) and GA won't send any events then.

This can be fixed.

##### GA UA

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-YY', {
  cookieFlags: 'samesite=none;secure'
});
```

[developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#cookie_flags)

##### GA UA (with gtag)

```
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-YY', {
  'cookie_flags': 'samesite=none;secure'
});
```

[developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cookies-user-id#cookie_flags)

##### GA4

```
gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXX', {
  'cookie_flags': 'samesite=none;secure'
});
```

[developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/config#cookie_flags)